# for-loop java not working

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I got 2 files(nodes and cost) in the following format

Node file as (Startnode, endnode)

```
A B
A C
```

Cost file as(node, cost)

```
A 6
B 5
C 8
```

If the startnode specified by the user is 'A' , then the following method should search for A in node file and then add the corresponding end nodes (in this case B, C)
to the list `neighbournodes` and if those end nodes match the nodes in cost file, then those corresponding costs (in this case 5, 8) should be added to list `h_cost`

So, I got the following loop to do this. my `neighbournodes` is working fine (i.e. it is outputting B,C) but somehow my `h_cost` doesn't output 5, 8 instead it is outputting the empty list.

```
 for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if(startnode.equalsIgnoreCase(nodes[i].getStartNode()))
        {
            neighbournodes.add(nodes[i].getEndNode());
            int newi = i;
             if(nodes[newi].getEndNode().equalsIgnoreCase(cost[i].getNode()))
                {
                    h_cost.add(cost[i].getCost()); 

                }

        }
    }
    System.out.println("neighbouring nodes are "+neighbournodes);
    System.out.println("H_cost is "+h_cost);
```

I am not sure where my loop is faulty, can any one be able to let me know where I am going wrong? Am I supposed to use enhanced for loop?

Comment: we have no idea how you defined the functions you are using in this for loop..

Comment: can you post the methods `getStartNode()`, `getEndNode()`, `getCost()`? and also where are you assigning the `startnode`, `nodes` and `cost` variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using the same index variables for the loops. Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    if(startnode.equalsIgnoreCase(nodes[i].getStartNode())) {

    neighbournodes.add(nodes[i].getEndNode());

        for(int j = 0; j < cost.length; j++) {

            if(nodes[i].getEndNode().equalsIgnoreCase(cost[j].getNode())) {

            h_cost.add(cost[j].getCost()); 

            }
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("neighbouring nodes are "+neighbournodes);
System.out.println("H_cost is "+h_cost);
```

The logic seems ok to me but using same index may mess up its value. Also I assume `cost.length` will be equal to entries in the cost file.